# AVADA Theme100% Height Scroll not working first page - help-me

Tags: css, scroll, height

Error page: https://boraassessoria.com.br/novo/cases-de-sucesso-3/

In avada theme I enabled Full Height and 100% Height Scroll. But scrolling down is like having an invisible page, so I have to scroll twice to achieve the default scroll effect. But he should have come down the first time. I can't find the error at all. Can anyone help?

- double mouse scroll

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's like activating the fusion-scroll-section-element active class twice